# Failed to map file - TWRP on KLTE

Tags: root-access, twrp, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I am trying to update my `su` binary. I previously used SuperSU, but switched to CWM SuperUser and now it is telling me to update my `su` binary. It tells me to reboot to recovery mode which works and tries automaticaly to flash the zip. But when viewing the log, an error message shows:

```
Failed to map file: /cache/superuser.zip
Flashing zip failed.
```

I have tried manually copying the `su` binary but SuperUser still prompts me to update it. I have tried moving the zip file and flashing it from a different location, but I still get `Failed to map file...`. I am using TWRP 3.0.2-2 on SM-G900F (Samsung Galaxy S5 [klte] International) with stock Android 6.0.1.